# Adding a constraint to FindRoot

Tags: equation-solving

I want to solve a system of two equations using `FindRoot` and at the same time I want to bound the solution in a specific interval: [-180,180].

My current code is:

```
dtr=Pi/180;a1=1;e1=0;w1=16*dtr;q1=0;i1=0;
a2=0.48;e2=0.6;w2=176*dtr;q2=0;i2=60*dtr;r1=4;r2=6;
f1=2(r1 Cos[v1] Cos[w1] Sin[i1]-r1 Sin[i1] Sin[v1] Sin[w1])(r1 Cos[w1] Sin[i1] Sin[v1]-r2 Cos[w2] Sin[i2] Sin[v2]+r1 Cos[v1] Sin[i1] Sin[w1]-r2 Cos[v2] Sin[i2] Sin[w2])+2(r1 Cos[i1] Cos[v1] Cos[w1]-r1 Cos[i1] Sin[v1] Sin[w1])(r1 Cos[i1] Cos[w1] Sin[v1]+r1 Cos[i1] Cos[v1] Sin[w1]-r2 Sin[v2](Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Cos[q1-q2]+Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2])-r2 Cos[v2](-Cos[w2] Sin[q1-q2]-Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2]))+2(-r1 Cos[w1] Sin[v1]-r1 Cos[v1] Sin[w1])(r1 Cos[v1] Cos[w1]-r1 Sin[v1] Sin[w1]-r2 Sin[v2](-COS[q1-q2] Sin[w2]+Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Sin[q1-q2])-r2 Cos[v2](Cos[w2] Cos[q1-q2]+Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2]));
f2=2(r1 Cos[w1] Sin[i1] Sin[v1]-r2 Cos[w2] Sin[i2] Sin[v2]+r1 Cos[v1] Sin[i1] Sin[w1]-r2 Cos[v2] Sin[i2] Sin[w2])(-r2 Cos[v2] Cos[w2] Sin[i2]+r2 Sin[i2]Sin[v2] Sin[w2])+2(r1 Cos[i1] Cos[w1] Sin[v1]+r1 Cos[i1] Cos[v1] Sin[w1]-r2 Sin[v2](Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Cos[q1-q2]+Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2])-r2 Cos[v2](-Cos[w2] Sin[q1-q2]-Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2]))(-r2 Cos[v2](Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Cos[q1-q2]+Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2])+r2 Sin[v2](-Cos[w2] Sin[q1-q2]-Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2]))+2(r1 Cos[v1] Cos[w1]-r1 Sin[v1] Sin[w1]-r2 Sin[v2](-Cos[q1-q2] Sin[w2]+Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Sin[q1-q2])-r2 Cos[v2](Cos[w2] Cos[q1-q2]+Cos[i2]Sin[w2]Sin[q1-q2]))(-r2Cos[v2](-Cos[q1-q2]Sin[w2]+Cos[i2]Cos[w2]Sin[q1-q2])+r2Sin[v2](Cos[w2]Cos[q1-q2]+Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1-q2]));
z1=Table[i,{i,-180,180,1}]*dtr;z2=Table[i,{i,-180,180,1}]*dtr;
R=FindRoot[{f1==0,f2==0}, {{v1,z1,-180*dtr,180*dtr}, {v2,z2,-180*dtr,180*dtr}}]
```

Unfortunately I didn't get any results so how can I bound my roots to be between `-180*dtr` and `180`.

Comment: Consider using the Weierstrass substitution, so that you sidestep the problem of non-unique angles.

Comment: If you do FullSimplify[{f1==0, f2==0, -Pi<v1<Pi, -Pi<v2<Pi}] you will see that your problem is not as complicated as it otherwise appears.

Comment: i didn't get that ,i have already simplified each of f1 and f2 before using FindRoots  ,

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your specific example, you only need to eliminate the syntax errors in your code (some `COs` instead of `Cos` and some spaces missing) to get a valid result

```
R = FindRoot[{f1 == 0, f2 == 0}, {{v1, 0}, {v2, 0}}]
(* {v1 -> -0.216259, v2 -> 0.126596} *)
```

I am not exactly sure what you try to achieve by passing a table as a second item in the parameter list. Usually, that position is for the starting value, which is a single value and not a table. Remember that `FindRoot` will always find only one solution and that it will return one  "solution" even though it got stuck and that result is not actually a root. You need to check that afterward yourself.

Also note that for a single variable it is possible to specify the range, but not so for two or more variables. You might, however, use a trick and add some function that is zero in your search interval and very large (at least larger than your actual function) outside. One option might be

```
constrain[v1_, v2_] := Exp[100 (Abs[v1] - 180)] Exp[100 (Abs[v2] - 180)]
```

which you just add to your actual function

```
R = FindRoot[{f1 + constrain[v1, v2] == 0, f2 + constrain[v1, v2] == 0}, {{v1, 0}, {v2, 0}}]
(* {v1 -> -0.216259, v2 -> 0.126596} *)
```

**Edit:**

It is possible to specify search boundaries for two or more variables. However, that requires using the Secant method. For my own applications I found the default Newton algorithm to be more flexible and more robust. Therefore, if the Secant method does not work then the above suggestion is a possibility to restrict the search for the Newton algorithm.

Comment: The table of z1 and z2 is for the initial guess because i want to find the root by using more than one initial guess ,for example the first initial guess will give me a root then the second one and so on .In the constrain that you suggest would you tell me please whats 100 ?and why did you take the absolute for v1 .Thank you

Comment: If that is what you want, then you should use the answer by Bob. A single call to `FindRoot` will give you only one solution and accepts only a single parameter for `x0`. Regarding the parameters, I suggest you plot the function `constrain` and see what changes when you use different numbers.

Answer (score 1):

```
dtr = Pi/180; a1 = 1; e1 = 0; w1 = 16*dtr; q1 = 0; i1 = 0;
w2 = 176*dtr; q2 = 0; i2 = 60*dtr; r1 = 4; r2 = 6;
f1 = 2 (r1 Cos[v1] Cos[w1] Sin[i1] - 
       r1 Sin[i1] Sin[v1] Sin[w1]) (r1 Cos[w1] Sin[i1] Sin[v1] - 
       r2 Cos[w2] Sin[i2] Sin[v2] + r1 Cos[v1] Sin[i1] Sin[w1] - 
       r2 Cos[v2] Sin[i2] Sin[w2]) + 
    2 (r1 Cos[i1] Cos[v1] Cos[w1] - 
       r1 Cos[i1] Sin[v1] Sin[w1]) (r1 Cos[i1] Cos[w1] Sin[v1] + 
       r1 Cos[i1] Cos[v1] Sin[w1] - 
       r2 Sin[v2] (Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Cos[q1 - q2] + Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2]) - 
       r2 Cos[v2] (-Cos[w2] Sin[q1 - q2] - Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2])) + 
    2 (-r1 Cos[w1] Sin[v1] - r1 Cos[v1] Sin[w1]) (r1 Cos[v1] Cos[w1] - 
       r1 Sin[v1] Sin[w1] - 
       r2 Sin[v2] (-Cos[q1 - q2] Sin[w2] + Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Sin[q1 - q2]) - 
       r2 Cos[v2] (Cos[w2] Cos[q1 - q2] + Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2])) // 
   FullSimplify;
f2 = 2 (r1 Cos[w1] Sin[i1] Sin[v1] - r2 Cos[w2] Sin[i2] Sin[v2] + 
       r1 Cos[v1] Sin[i1] Sin[w1] - 
       r2 Cos[v2] Sin[i2] Sin[w2]) (-r2 Cos[v2] Cos[w2] Sin[i2] + 
       r2 Sin[i2] Sin[v2] Sin[w2]) + 
    2 (r1 Cos[i1] Cos[w1] Sin[v1] + r1 Cos[i1] Cos[v1] Sin[w1] - 
       r2 Sin[v2] (Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Cos[q1 - q2] + Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2]) - 
       r2 Cos[v2] (-Cos[w2] Sin[q1 - q2] - 
          Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2])) (-r2 Cos[
         v2] (Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Cos[q1 - q2] + Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2]) + 
       r2 Sin[v2] (-Cos[w2] Sin[q1 - q2] - Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2])) + 
    2 (r1 Cos[v1] Cos[w1] - r1 Sin[v1] Sin[w1] - 
       r2 Sin[v2] (-Cos[q1 - q2] Sin[w2] + Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Sin[q1 - q2]) - 
       r2 Cos[v2] (Cos[w2] Cos[q1 - q2] + 
          Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2])) (-r2 Cos[
         v2] (-Cos[q1 - q2] Sin[w2] + Cos[i2] Cos[w2] Sin[q1 - q2]) + 
       r2 Sin[v2] (Cos[w2] Cos[q1 - q2] + Cos[i2] Sin[w2] Sin[q1 - q2])) // 
   FullSimplify;
```

To accelerate the search, you can reduce the sampling used to search for roots.

```
z = Table[i, {i, -180, 180, 45}]*dtr;
```

Use [`Outer`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Outer.html) to do the grid search, [`Union`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Union.html) to eliminate duplicates, and [`DeleteCases`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DeleteCases.html) to exclude cases where the search stopped at the boundary.

**EDIT:** Corrected typo (slot number) in `Outer`

```
R = DeleteCases[
   Union[
    Outer[
      FindRoot[
        {f1 == 0, f2 == 0},
        {{v1, #1, -Pi, Pi}, {v2, #2, -Pi, Pi}}] &,
      z, z] // Flatten[#, 1] &,
    SameTest ->
     (Norm[({v1, v2} /. #1) - ({v1, v2} /. #2)] < 10^-6 &)],
   _?(Max[Abs[{v1, v2} /. #]] == Pi &)] // Quiet

(* {{v1 -> -1.83828, v2 -> 1.64646}, {v1 -> -1.7698, 
  v2 -> -1.4611}, {v1 -> -0.250229, v2 -> -3.08336}, {v1 -> -0.216259,
   v2 -> 0.126596}, {v1 -> 1.30331, v2 -> -1.49513}, {v1 -> 1.37179, 
  v2 -> 1.68049}, {v1 -> 2.89136, v2 -> 0.0582335}, {v1 -> 2.92533, 
  v2 -> -3.015}}  *)
```

Comment: Would you tell me please what is the # for ?

Comment: @sara, a tip: any time you find an unfamiliar symbol in *Mathematica*, highlight it and press F1.

Comment: @J.M.thank you for your help